# Which mouse button was clicked onmouseup in javascript?

Tags: javascript

let's say I have

```
  <div onmouseup="myfunction()">
  </div>
```

But how would I know if left or right mouse button was clicked?

Comment: Try to look into `event.which` property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent

Answer (score 3):

There are two properties for finding out which mouse button has been clicked: `which` and `button`. Please note that these properties don’t always work on a click event. To safely detect a mouse button you have to use the mousedown or mouseup events.

`which` is an old Netscape property. which will give below values for mouse buttons.

```
Left button - 1
Middle button - 2
Right Button - 3
```

No problems, except its meager support (and the fact that it’s also used for key detection).

Now button has been fouled up beyond all recognition. According to W3C its values should be:

```
Left button – 0
Middle button – 1
Right button – 2
```

According to Microsoft its values should be:

```
Left button – 1
Middle button – 4
Right button – 2
```

No doubt the Microsoft model is better than W3C’s. 0 should mean “no button pressed”, anything else is illogical.

Besides, only in the Microsoft model button values can be combined, so that 5 would mean “left and middle button”. Not even Explorer 6 actually supports this yet, but in the W3C model such a combination is theoretically impossible: you can never know whether the left button was also clicked.

and to check which type of button is clicked always use feature detection for `which` and `button` properties

```
if (e.which) {
   // old netsapce implementation
   consoel.log((e.which == 3) + ' right click');
} else if (e.button) {
   // for microsoft or W3C model implementation
   consoel.log((e.button == 2) + ' right click');
}
```

**Reference:**

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Checked this function:

```
function getEvt (evt) {
    var mouseEvt = (evt).which;
    var mMouseEvt = evt.button;
    console.log(mouseEvt);
    console.log(mMouseEvt);
}
```

It returns int. For example for left click:

```
1      listeners.js (line 43)
0      listeners.js (line 44)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var rightclick;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
    alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick); // true or false
}
```

Comment: good pick... you need to check my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953651/window-event-doesnt-work-in-firefox/9953733#9953733

Comment: The post I linked is older than yours

Comment: Both posts derive from QuirksMode, so neither one is original effort.